# jQuery Fadeout leaves small gap

Tags: jquery

I'm using the current jQuery to hide fade out a notification div, and then remove it, however when it completes there's an odd gap around the height of a `&nbsp;` - meaning that subsequent forms and page elements don't display where they were before the notice appeared.

To recap: the fade out and remove is working perfectly but I'd like the gap left over to vanish as well. It's a minor thing, but it's bothering me.

The jquery:

```
// Fade out any success divs.
$(".success").fadeOut(6000, function(){
    $(".success").remove();
});
```

The notification div is being written by PHP on postback, and has the following CSS:

```
.success {
    background-color: #b3ffb2;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.box {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

The div is very simple:

```
<div class="success box"><p><strong>Success!</strong><br />Done!</p></div>
```

Edit: The surrounding markup of the page looks like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="navigation">
        <ul> ... </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="container">
        <div class="success box">
            <p><strong>Sucess!</strong><br />
            Done</p>
        </div>
        // more content
    </div>

</div>
```

Edit: Using Firebug in FF 3.5.2, I can't see anything being left behind using the inspector. There's just an odd gap. I've also created a screenshot of this phenomena:

[image: odd gap]

Comment: What is the surrounding markup before (and, presumably, after) the <div> is added?

Comment: Thanks for looking Votey! Does this clear it up a bit?

Comment: Is this happening across all browsers or just in a particular browser (ie IE)?

Comment: Safari 4 (Mac), IE8 and Chrome (Win) all display the same issue.

Comment: so you don't see this issue when the page loads without a success message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without actually seeing it, I'd presume that it is an artifact of either `#container` or of `// more content`. `$.remove()` literally removes the element from the DOM and forces a redraw, so assuming that it's working (syntax appears fine), it is certainly not a result of .success.

Comment: Well, at least I have some ideas and inklings about where to go from here. I'll post as I have more success.

Comment: While I solved the question myself, it was your comment that assisted in solving. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

Try hide() instead of remove?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, there was a `<br>` tag hiding under my notice that was still there after fade out.

So, in order to hide the first element after the div, I changed my jquery to:

```
$(".success").fadeOut(6000, function(){
    $(".success + br").remove();
});
```

Which removes the very next item in the dom following the selector. From the [jQuery Manual](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/next#prevnext).